# Necesito ejecutar un query SQL en LINQ para regresar un listado de un Complex Type

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq

tengo un Complex type que se llama GraficaLD que tiene dos propiedades una propiedad int llamada Data y otra propiedad string llamada Label, lo que intento hacer es regresar una lista "List" ejecutando un query con LINQ

**Este es mi query SQL:**

```
select sum(HrsDayQty) Data, a.SpaDesc Label from HR.Kardex k 
join Catalogs.IncidenceTypes it on k.IncTypeId = it.Id
join Hr.Employees e on k.EmpId = e.Id
join Catalogs.Cells c on e.CellId = c.Id
join Catalogs.Areas a on c.AreaId = a.Id
where it.Family = 'AUS'
group by a.SpaDesc
```

**Esto es lo que deseo regresar:**

```
List<GraficaLD> PorArea = /*Codigo LINQ aqui*/;
```

**Esta es la clase GraficaLD:**

```
public partial class GraficaLD
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        public double Data { get; set; }
    }
```

**Esto es un codigo que no he podido hacer funcionar:**

```
    List<GraficaLD> PorArea = (from k in db.Kardex 
group k by k.Employees.Cells.Areas.SpaDesc into kGroup
        select new GraficaLD {
        Data = kGroup.Sum(a=> a.HrsDayQty),
        Label = 
        }).ToList<GraficaLD>();
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: A nivel de entidades de tienes una relacion entre Kardex y Areas ? Estas usando EntityFramework ?

Comment: Siempre recomiendo lo mismo, no saldría mucho menos engorroso crear un sp y llamarlo desde código? ;)

Comment: Si hay relaciones y si estoy utilizando EF, gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: Ya lo hice funcionar desde un store procedure. Todo esto es para llenar unas graficas con un query diferente para cada una de las graficas y no me gustaria tener que hacer un SP para cada una de las graficas